# "Trickle-down" custom JavaScript events

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I'm looking into custom events in JavaScript.

According to MDN, using the CustomEvent constructor, there is an option to make the event "bubble up" (false by default):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent#CustomEventInit

Example:

```
// add an appropriate event listener
obj.addEventListener("cat", function(e) { process(e.detail) });

// create and dispatch the event
var event = new CustomEvent("cat", {"detail":{"hazcheeseburger":true}});
obj.dispatchEvent(event);
```

I tested it on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ppx4gcxe/

And the bubble up functionality seems to work. But I'd like my custom event to "trickle down", that is to trigger even listeners on child elements; the opposite of bubbling up.

I vaguely remember some default browser events "trickling down". This was supposedly one of these points of contention in the early browser days.

Anyway, is there any way to get this functionality on my custom events? Any relatively easy and straightforward way, of course. I don't really want to write a function to traverse all child elements and manually trigger any listeners on them. I hope there's another way.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're looking for is called `event capturing` (the opposite of `event bubbling`).  You can enable `event capturing` by passing in `true` as the third argument to `addEventListener`.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/zs1a6ywo/

NOTE: `event capturing` is not supported in IE 8 or below.

For more information, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: Thanks. Although it does sound like the correct answer at first, it is not exactly what I want. My code does "two", "one", yours does "one", "two". The result I want is "two", "four". Anyway, it sounds complicated in any case, and in my case I figured that the simplest solution is a custom "event bus" to which I can hook listeners and fire custom events.

Comment: @Rolf Did you mean to have `four` be a child of `two`?  Either way,  would it work for you to bind the event to `document.querySelector('#two *')` while using `event capturing`?  That would hit `one`, `two`, and `four`.  You could then check inside of your handler to see if `event.target` is a parent of `event.currentTarget`.  If so, then the event is "valid."  If not, it is "invalid" and should be ignored.  That would get you `two` and `four` only.

Comment: Correction: You could then check inside of your handler to see if `two` is a parent of or equal to `e.currentTarget`.  If so, then the event is "valid."  If not, it is "invalid" and should be ignored.

e.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/ss4myz18/

(Obviously that can be refactored to be much cleaner)

Comment: I meant to for the event to "trickle down" on child nodes. I think this happens with some default events. I gave up the whole trickle down or bubble up thing for custom events, and just use an "event bus" class to register and trigger my custom events globally, without worrying too much about event propagation. I think it has the functionality you described.